# How to escape # character in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to output some text with hot string. All work well except when using the # character. It produces unexpected results.

:*:.ef::C# Entity framework{Space}

I tried to escape it with ` char, with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- !, {, }, # etc, are [special key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames)s that must be enclosed in braces to be sent:

  ```
  :*:.ef::C{#} Entity framework{Space}
  ```

or

- If you have AHK v1.1.27+ use the [T option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#T) for the hotstring:

  ```
  :*T:.ef::C# Entity framework ` ; to send a space at the end add an ` char after it
  ```