# AutoHotkey hotstring not replacing trigger text containing "!b" correctly

Tags: autohotkey, ahk2

I'm having trouble with an AutoHotkey script where a hotstring isn't replacing the trigger text correctly.

Here's the specific line of code I used:

```
:*:;container;::>[!blank-container|float-left-small]
```

I expect that when I type `;container;`, it should be replaced with **>[!blank-container|float-left-small]**.

However, instead of getting the expected output, I'm getting **>[lank-container|float-left-small]**.

It seems that the replacement text is ignoring the characters "`!b`" from the output

I've tried removing any conflicting commands, like the backspace command (`Send {backspace 11}`), but the issue persists.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the bang (!)?  Maybe it has meaning to AHK.

Comment: @Tim I am new to AHK. How should I escape the (!)?? I feel it is the `!b` that is causing the issue.

Comment: Like this: [How to escape # character in AHK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69527268/how-to-escape-character-in-ahk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the **Send** command or **Hotstrings** are used in their default
(non-raw) mode, characters such as **{}^!+#** have special meaning.
To use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
braces:

```
:*:;container;::>[{!}blank-container|float-left-small]
```

or use the **raw mode**:

```
:*R:;container;::>[!blank-container|float-left-small]
```

or the **[Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotstrings.htm#T) (recommended)**:

```
:*T:;container;::>[!blank-container|float-left-small]
```

See also [Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/EscapeChar.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. However, what is the difference between RAW mode and Text mode?

Comment: See [Raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Raw) and [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Text).